# How can I bind a single username to a single password when they are in separate lists?

Tags: python, list

How can I bind a single username to a single password when they are in separate lists?

```
#Bank App that asks user for their username and password at login screen
    #creating empty lists everytime the file is initialized
    username_list = ["ErikMendez", "Reinhardt", "Batman"]
    password_list = ["Mendez1995", "Honor&Glory", "I'mBatman"]
    balance_list = ["100.0", "500.0", "900.0"]

    #function creates a new client
    def newClient():
        username = ""
        password = ""

        while username not in username_list and len(username) <= 4:
            username = input("Create a username for this new account: ")
            if username not in username_list:
                username_list.append(username)
                print("Your username has been successfully saved.")
                break
            print("That username is already in taken.")
            answer = input("Are you already a member of this bank?: y/n")
            if answer.lower() == "y":
                returningClient()
            else:
                newClient()

        while len(password) <= 4:
            password = input("Please assign a password to this account: ")
            if len(password) >= 4:
                password_list.append(password)
                print("Your password has been successfully saved.")
                break

            print("Password must be at least 4 characters long.")
        return username, password

    #Function to check returning client
    def returningClient():
        username = ""
        while username not in username_list:
            username = input("Enter your username: ")
            if username not in username_list:
                print("Error - It appears that your username is not in our system.")
                again = input("Try entering your username again or type 'Create' to register a new account.")
                if again == "Create".lower():
                    newClient()
                else:
                    returningClient()
            elif username in username_list:
                password = ""
                while password not in password_list:
                    password = input("Enter your password: ")
                    if password not in password_list:
                        print("Password does not match username.")
                    elif password in password_list:
                        print("Welcome " + username)
            else:
                print("Error")
                returningClient()


    returningClient()
```

Comment: Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: use a `dict`? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing into arrays in the first place and then manipulating, you can store straight into dictionaries!

For instance,

`first_user = { 'username' : "ErikMendez", 'password' : "Mendez1995", 'balance' : 100.0 }`

Afterwards, you can access the dictionary by key values. For example, `first_user['username']` returns the string `ErikMendez`.

If you want to be able to create and access a list containing these bindings, you could do this:

```
list = []
first_user = { 'username' : "ErikMendez", 'password' : "Mendez1995" }
list.append(first_user)
print(list[0]['username']) # prints ErikMendez
print(list[0]['password']) # prints Mendez1995
```

## Edit:

Based on Blckknght's suggestion, here's something even better you can do: since dictionaries are based on `'key' : 'value'` pairs, you could use `username`'s as keys and use another dictionary as `value`s to store the info! For instance:

```
user_dictionary = { 
    'ErikMendez' : { 'password' : "Mendez1995", 'balance' : 100.0 }, 
    'Reinhardt' : { 'password' : "Honor&Glory", 'balance' : 500.0 } 
}
```

You can access this dictionary using

```
print(user_dictionary['ErikMendez']) # prints { 'password' : "Mendez1995", 'balance' : 100.0 }
print(user_dictionary['ErikMendez']['password']) # prints Mendez1995
```

Comment: While your main point (use dictionaries!) is a good one, I think you've missed a major advantage of dicts: It's very efficient to look up a value in a dictionary when you know the key. So rather than creating one dict per user, and then putting all the dicts in a list, I'd suggest using the usernames as the keys in a large dict that contains data on all the bank's users. You'd could either have separate dictionaries for the passwords and the balances, or a single dict with mapping from user names to combined `password, balance` values.

Comment: Good point, I forgot about that! Plus, I wanted to answer the specific question: how to bind a username and password. I'll edit my answer to provide your better solution. Thanks!

Comment: These are great suggestions. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi @ErikMendez, please select my response as the answer if it helped :)